# how do movl operation of the form memaddress(, REG, int) work?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I know how move operations normally work but the fact that this one does not have an input is tripping me up.

Comment: movl 0x3033c0(,%rsi,3),%eax

Comment: I don't think the multiplier can be `3`, but see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It just means you don't have a base register. The full syntax is:

```
offset(base, index, scale)
```

Meaning something like this C pseudocode:

```
*(uint32_t *)(base + index*scale + offset)
```

In your case, `base` would just be `0`.

Reference: http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/CPU/x86/lecture.html#X77_0100_sib_byte_layout

Comment: so we are moving to offset + multiplier*index?